# Distinct Values with criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table in the format given below:

```
Account Programme View
A   1
B   0
A   1
A   1
C   1
C   1
D   0
E   1
D   0
E   1
G   0
B   0
```

How do I get the unique accounts with programme view 1. Here the answer is `3 (A, C & E)`. I used `Sum(if(frequency....)` but getting stuck in defining the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right lines, though `FREQUENCY` needs to be combined with `MATCH` to count text:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$13=0,MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0)),IF($B$2:$B$13=0,MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0)))>0,1))`

Don't forget this is an array formula so confirm by holding `Ctrl` + `Shift` then hit `Enter`

Assuming Account is in column A and Programme View in column B. You cna then change the `$B$2:$B$13=0` to reference a cell such as `$B$2:$B$13=$D2` to use the formula in a table.

**EDIT: Adding Further Criteria**

To add a further column for criteria you add an additional `IF`. Say you were to have column C with maybe Account Active, filled with Yes and No you could do something like:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$13=0,IF($C$2:$C$13="Yes",MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0))),IF($B$2:$B$13=0,IF($C$2:$C$13="Yes",MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0))))>0,1))`

This would only count Accounts where the Programme View was `0` and the account was active.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Sir. Could you please tell me if I were to add more criteria, how would I proceed?